# develop an extension chrome to visualize data from google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

1. trying to use a google analytics API to retrieve the data and display it when you click on the extension.
2. Is there any way to query google analytics in extension chrome ?

Comment: 2: Yes, the same way you would do it on a webpage. Use ajax; [fetch()](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data), [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or for example [jquery ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: Welcome! This question runs the risk of getting closed because it doesn't provide any code to show what you've already tried. You might like to read the guide on how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Cheers!